# How to insert .flv in iTunes library

Tags: itunes, video

I have downloaded a flv file, and I would like to save it in iTunes library for later play. I guess I should convert it first, but is this supported by OSX or do I need an extra application. And which file format will keep the quality and the size of original video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert it to the mp4 and insert it. I use [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) to convert or fix indexes.

Also you can give a try to Perian if it'll work in your OS.

Comment: [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) is great! thanks for sharing. It's far better than wondershare and I hope it stays free.

Comment: Handbrake is clutch. A+

Answer (score 3):

[SmartConverter](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/smart-converter/id447513724) is a free app available on the AppStore and that does the job.  It has the added benefit over Handbrake that for `.flv` files it will just change the container and not actually re-encode the video.  Which is quicker and doesn't make you loose quality.

The downside of SmartConverter is the ads displayed and that you cannot do batches of conversions.  For that you need to buy the pro version.